# Double linear fitting in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have the following data:

```r
df <- structure(list(x = c(0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15), 
                     y = c(0.51,0.71, 0.8, 1.12, 2.05, 3.23, 4.45)), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df
#>      x    y
#> 1  0.0 0.51
#> 2  2.5 0.71
#> 3  5.0 0.80
#> 4  7.5 1.12
#> 5 10.0 2.05
#> 6 12.5 3.23
#> 7 15.0 4.45

plot(df)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This data can be fitted with a **double-linear** function, like the following:

```
if(x < bkp) {
  y <- i1 + s1 * x
} else {
  y <- (i1 + s1 * bkp) + s2 * (x - bkp)
}
```

where `bkp` is the breaking point (somewhere between `7.5` and `10`), `i1` is the `y-intercept`, and `s1` and `s2` are the `slopes`.

I know this can be achieved using the `segmented` package like the following:

```r
library(segmented)

df <- structure(list(x = c(0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15), 
                     y = c(0.51,0.71, 0.8, 1.12, 2.05, 3.23, 4.45)), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))

fit_df <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)

segmented(fit_df)
#> Warning in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts): non-list contrasts
#> argument ignored
#> Call: segmented.lm(obj = fit_df)
#> 
#> Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
#> (Intercept)            x         U1.x  
#>      0.4970       0.0768       0.4032  
#> 
#> Estimated Break-Point(s):
#> psi1.x  
#>   8.07
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, I would like to translate this function:

```
if(x < bkp) {
  y <- i1 + s1 * x
} else {
  y <- (i1 + s1 * bkp) + s2 * (x - bkp)
}
```

In order to achieve the same results. Any ideas?

Comment: If it might be of some use, I got an OK fit to a simple exponential equation "y = a * exp(b * x)" with fitted parameters a = 4.0275246876414617E-01 and b = 1.6137389391657100E-01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd fit it using `optim` and a cost function. To start, I create the data frame.

```r
# Data frame
df <- structure(list(x = c(0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15), 
                     y = c(0.51,0.71, 0.8, 1.12, 2.05, 3.23, 4.45)), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Next, I define the model function. Notice that I use `ifelse` to concisely toggle the part of the function to the right of the break point.

```r
# Linear model with break point
model <- function(x, par){
  par[1] + par[2] * x + ifelse(x > par[4], par[3] * (x - par[4]), 0)
}
```

Then, I define the cost function. This calculates the sum of the squared residuals, which will be minimised to fit the model.

```r
# Cost function
cost <- function(par, df_data = df){
  sum((df_data$y - model(df_data$x, par))^2)
}
```

I call `optim` to minimise the cost function and plot the results.

```r
# Minimise cost function
fit <- optim(c(0, 0.1, 2, 7), cost)

# Plot results
plot(df)
lines(0:15, model(0:15, fit$par))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

PS The parameters estimated by the fit are as follows:

```r
# 0.50036077 0.07611683 0.40440741 8.07065399
```

which are in close agreement with the `segmented` package:

```r
# 0.4970     0.0768     0.4032     8.07
```